# Is it possible to override the pricing for an in-app subscription purchase when adding a country in the Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

When creating [in-app billing subscription](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) item in Google Play, one can only set the price before the item is activated.  After that changing the price is not allowed (since that would affect existing subscribers).

Since each country can potentially have a different price, this means that dozens or hundreds of prices must be set before activation.  But you can only set the price for countries that are active.  If you start with a subset of active countries and then later add new countries after the in-app purchase is active, it will auto-convert to the currency based on your default price.

This is a problem for me as I set specific prices in different countries, but I do not want to  launch all countries day one.  Is there any way to set the prices at the time new countries are added?  Otherwise the only solution is to create new in-app purchases and manually set all the prices/localization details (a very laborious and error-prone manual process) over and over every time we launch a country.